# How do you embed unity games with html onto websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, unity-game-engine

Im trying to embed a unity game onto my [website](https://math.framer.photos/) but i really cant find out how.This is the [file](https://mdtowerz.itch.io/ryfg). Can someone please help me with this?

I tried multiple things like github but it doesn't work. i even tried using the code from other exported unity projects but it didn't work.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Unity discussion](https://discussions.unity.com/t/putting-game-on-website/32805), You can upload it to something like dropbox or github. Then past in your website an iframe of the link. something like this:

```
<iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="https://link...">
```